# Removing repeated lines from text file

Tags: python

I need to remove the duplicated lines from the txt file, i.e.:

```
ATOM      1  N   MET B   1      43.567   2.228  13.359  1.00159.33           N  
ATOM      2  N   MET B   1      43.391   2.228  74.594  1.00159.33           N  
ATOM      3  CA  MET B   1      42.581   2.361  14.428  1.00160.56           C  
ATOM      4  CA  MET B   1      44.377   2.361  73.525  1.00160.56           C
```

so I would like to remove lines:

```
ATOM      2  N   MET B   1      43.391   2.228  74.594  1.00159.33           N  
ATOM      4  CA  MET B   1      44.377   2.361  73.525  1.00160.56           C
```

I've tried to achieve this by using this code, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
f=open("A.pdb").readlines()
lis=[]
for line in f:
    lis.append(line)
print (lis) 
length=len(lis)
element=0
array=[]
while element<length:
    if lis[element][13:16] == lis[element+1][13:16]:
        array.append(element)


for elements in array:
    lis.pop(array[elements])
```

Comment: Whats error you got ? you are using `element` in while loop but its not incremented in any where. While loop will run for ever :(

Comment: Why? They all have different set of values?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not good. You'd better say what actually went wrong. Any error message? What result did you get? And what did you expected? That'd ebe much more helpful

Comment: There are multiple ways in which this is broken: (1) You don't increment the index `element` in the `while` loop. (2) Even if you were to it'd still break because you'd be accessing beyond the bounds of the list.

Comment: You want to compare only last column ? like `N` and `C` ?

Comment: I don't get error message, the program suspends and never finishes.
Lafada - this is 3rd columnn

Comment: @AirelleJab what do you want ?

Comment: @dhana I want to remove the line+1 which has the same 3rd column as line. I compare only two lines - line and line+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version changes 'N N N CA CA N' to 'N CA N', is this your requirement?

```
result = []
previous_keyword = None
with open('A.pdb') as f:
    for line in f:
        # use these five lines if keyword is fixed at 3rd column, and columns are separated by whitespace
        try:
            keyword = line.split()[2]
        except:
            print('Line with unknown format: ' + line)
            continue

        # use this one if the keyword is fixed at position[13:16]
        #keyword = line[13:16]

        if keyword != previous_keyword:
            result.append(line)
            #result.append(line.rstrip())     use this one if you don't want trailing 'newline'
            previous_keyword = keyword

for x in result:
    print x
```

The reason why your program "suspends and never finishes": within this iteration, you never increase 'element'

```
while element<length:
    if lis[element][13:16] == lis[element+1][13:16]:
        array.append(element)
```

Comment: @AirelleJab, if line 1,2,4 is "N"; line 3 is "CA", do you also want to remove line 4? (I don't have enough reputation to add comment under your question.

Comment: No, only if it is directly under the line